# How to override auth login function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to override laravel's default login function, however I am confused by the code I find there. I do not understand how laravel AuthenticatesUsers.php verifies that user exists in db and then authenticates the user.

I've come to this function in **AuthenticatesUsers.php**

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

I guess I would need to override this function inside auth/LoginController.php

but I do not understand how it works. Where are `guard()` and `attempt()` implemented, I guess the real action happens there. I need to add another condition to the login.

Anyone understands how laravel's default login works? and those two functions `guard()` and `attempt()`, for example attempt is not implemented inside AuthenticatesUsers.php itself and I believe its this function I should really override.

Where can I find it's implementation?

Comment: $this->guard() returns a guard instance if you look at the guard() method in AuthenticatesUsers. So attempt() is called from laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php.

Comment: If you use sublime/vscode/phpmyadmin , go to definition should work. But what do you wan to do exactly ? i don't think you need to overwrite attempt unless you want to change the way laravel authenticates users which might need some work and attention.

Comment: Also, look at your config/auth.php file. That's where laravel pulls the default model for the default guard, and figures out what DB table to use to authenticate. That's also the file you'll modify if you need to add a different guard and model for your logins.

Comment: I would like to add another condition to the login attempt function, I am implementing is_activated on user, I've added new column that will indicate if user has verified and activated his account. So I thought I need to override attempt, but upon closer inspection that may not be the case? Whats the best way to do this? I do not want to use any packages to accomplish this but implement it my self.

Comment: Oh, why not just check that at the controller level? On your login method find the user trying to login before you call the authentication's login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not overriding any functions, instead create a new `guard` and `provider`. Look at the `config/auth.php` to see how they are defined.

Then you can set your custom guard as default and the normal auth flow will take over.

See the documentation on [Adding Custom Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-guards)

Comment: If I implement custom Guard, what happens to all the nice things like throttling and error messages that laravels default guard implements.

Comment: You still have that all available, that's the benefit of the guard and provider approach. They implement a contract so your solution plays nicely with the framework.

Comment: perfect, thanks for your suggestion :) I'll mark it as correct answer since nobody else posted one here and this sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have just changed HomeController.php - using 'guest' as the middleware instead of 'auth'. For anyone in a similar situation, this works as a temporary solution.